# Database search in visual C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

In my program, i implemented a simple database search that takes in a string (name or part of the name) and returns the corresponding details:

```
string nameSearch = textBox1.Text;
DataRow[] resultRows;

resultRows = ds1.Tables["Lecturers"].Select("Name='" + nameSearch + "'");
```

But i'm not getting the expected results unless i type in the ENTIRE NAME correctly. How can i modify the 'Select()' to get results when i input only a part of the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick check of [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) on MSDN leads you to [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)...

```
resultRows = ds1.Tables["Lecturers"].Select("Name like '%" + nameSearch + "&'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `RowFilter` as in the below example:

```
ds1.Tables["Lecturers"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Name] LIKE '"+ nameSearch +"'"; 
DataTable dtOutput = ds1.Tables["Lecturers"].DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: You don't "need" too, this is just an alternative method

Answer (score 0):

use Name LIKE '% + namesearch + '%

Answer (score 0):

Try this?:

```
resultRows = ds1.Tables["Lecturers"].Select("Name like '%" + nameSearch + "%'");
```

I'm assuming this is not 'production' code.  Looks like a big [sql injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1) here.